# How to check for multiple sequences in 1 array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sequence, days

I have been looking for a solution for my problem but couldn't find, so I thought I'd ask. 
I currently have an array that contains the number of days a company is opened, from these days I have the numeric values.

So if a company is open 7 days a week I'd have:

```
$days= array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6');
```

If the company is closed on  Thursday the array would change to:

```
$days= array('0','1','2','4','5','6');'
```

Now my end goal is to get the first and last day of all consecutive days.
So 0-6 in the first example.

And for the second example (since the company is only closed on Thursday) I'd like to show: Friday-Wednesday, so that would be 4-2.

Anyone with any ideas on this? Because I am pretty stuck.

Comment: Your desire to wrap the dates (as opposed to doing 'Monday-Wednesday, Friday-Sunday') makes it difficult. What do you want something like `array(0, 2, 4, 6)` to return?

Comment: Just the days separate values 0, 2, 4, 6

Comment: So in that case it should give `Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Sunday`? Or `Wednesday, Friday, Sunday-Monday`? Or what?

Comment: What is the input to this function?

Comment: What if company is closed on 2 days? Tuesday and Thursday? What will be the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code and it works on single closed day or even multiple closed days.

```
$days= array('0','1','2','4','5','6');
$closed_days = range(1,max($days));   
$missing = array_diff($closed_days,$days);

$start_day = $days[0];
$end_day = $days[count($days) -1];

if(count($missing)>0){
    $first_key = key($missing);
    $next_key = $first_key+count($missing) - 1;
    if(count($missing) == 1){
        $next_key++;
    }
    $previous_key = $first_key;

    $start_day = $days[$next_key];
    $end_day = $days[$previous_key];
}

echo $start_day.'-'.$end_day;
```